# preg_match error and debugging php code

Tags: php, ioncube

Please help. I'm getting this error:

> ( ! ) Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'b' in C:\wamp\www\pmd\install\ioncube_checker.php on line 22

When I run the following code:

```
function system_info($php_info) {
$server_info = array();
$server_info['thread_safe'] = 'false';
$server_info['debug_build'] = 'false';
$server_info['php_ini_path'] = '';

foreach (explode("\n",$php_info) as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/command/',$line)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (preg_match('/thread safety.*(enabled|yes)/Ui',$line)) {
        $server_info['thread_safe'] = 'true';
    }

    if (preg_match('/debug.*(enabled|yes)/Ui',$line)) {
        $server_info['debug_build'] = 'true';
    }


    if (preg_match("/configuration file.*(</b></td><TD ALIGN=\"left\">| => |v\">)([^ <]*)(.*</td>*)?/",$line,$match)) {
        $server_info['php_ini_path'] = $match[2];

        if (!@file_exists($php_ini_path)) {
            $server_info['php_ini_path'] = '';
        }
    }

    $cgi_cli = ((strpos(php_sapi_name(),'cgi') !== false) || (strpos(php_sapi_name(),'cli') !== false));
    $cgi_cli ? $server_info['cgi_cli'] = 'true' : $server_info['cgi_cli'] = 'false'; 
}
return $server_info;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `/` as the regex delimiter you need to escape any `/` with a `\`. However, it's much easier to use a different delimiter when dealing with HTM:

```
preg_match("/configuration file.*(</b></td><TD ALIGN=\"left\">| => |v\">)([^ <]*)(.*</td>*)?/",$line,$match)
```

should be

```
preg_match("#configuration file.*(</b></td><TD ALIGN=\"left\">| => |v\">)([^ <]*)(.*</td>*)?#",$line,$match)
```

However, you should consider [**not using regexes to parse HTML at all**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/298479) - using a DOM engine is much better for it, and PHP already [has one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).